# DDOSLogger.sharedInstance logging only seems to log error level logging in console app

Tags: cocoalumberjack

Using the typical `DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance, with: .all)` code to add the OSLog output to CocoaLumberjack logging in my iOS app.

When I look at the console for the app running in the iOS simulator I see `error` level logging, but nothing more (particularly, no `debug` level logging). This is in a DEBUG build of the app and it has:

```
#if DEBUG
    dynamicLogLevel = DDLogLevel.debug
#else
    dynamicLogLevel = DDLogLevel.error
#endif
```

I suspect this is a configuration/setup problem but I have not been able to figure it out.

One more clue: `os_log("test via os_log")` does show up in console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default behaviour of `Console.app` is to hide the info/debug messages.

To view them, in the `Console.app`, select `Include Info/Debug Messages` from the `Action Menu`.

More info here: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/1006#issuecomment-451435346.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the thread in the CocoaLumberjack issues -- that tracks with exactly what I have seen. There is a known issue with logging from iOS apps to the Console -- this is an Apple issue -- looks our app and CocoaLumberjack are doing the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have to say, that is NOT obvious place to look. Took me a few hours trying to find inexistent bug in my application beforehand